# Drop down values doesn't apply

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

all
Assume I have such a code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     </head>
     <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    var figure = document.getElementById("tool");
    var selected = figure.options[figure.selectedIndex].value;


    if(selected === "pencil"){ 
    alert("Like a pencil");
}

if(selected === 'line'){
alert("Just drag and drop");
}
if(selected === "rect"){ 
    alert("drag and drop for rect");
}
    </script>


    <p><label>Drawing tool: <select id="tool">
        <option value="pencil">Pencil</option>
        <option value="rect">Rectangle</option>
        <option value="line">Line</option>
    </select></label></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Why, when I'll change value of droplist it doesn't react? Maybe I should add OnChange? But I didn't get how it works...
Thank you

Comment: Your code is executed once when the page loads. You need to look at event handlers, specifically listening for the `change` event in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put that code into an event listener, like:

```
figure.addEventListener('change', function(){    
  // your code...   
});
```

And put your script at the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add en [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener). Your current code just runs once when the page loads.

```
window.onload(function() {
   document.getElementById("tool").addEventListener('change',toolChangeEventHandler);
}

function toolChangeEventHandler() {
    if(this.value === "pencil"){ 
        alert("Like a pencil");
    } else if(this.value === "line"){
        alert("Just drag and drop");
    } else if(this.value === "rect"){ 
        alert("drag and drop for rect");
    }
}
```

The onload event is needed to ensure that the element exists when you attempt to add the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
 var figure = document.getElementById("tool");
    var selected = figure.options[figure.selectedIndex].value;


    if(selected === "pencil"){ 
    alert("Like a pencil");
}

if(selected === 'line'){
alert("Just drag and drop");
}
if(selected === "rect"){ 
    alert("drag and drop for rect");
}
```

is executed when your page loads. To exec this code when the select change, you could use an event listener (methods are not the same in all browser) as above or set the callback like this (more simpler for a single event) :

```
<select id="tool" onchange="onSelectChange(this);">...
```

Where onSelectChange is a function like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onSelectChange = function(elt) {
        var selected = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

        if(selected === "pencil"){ 
            alert("Like a pencil");
        }
        if(selected === 'line'){
            alert("Just drag and drop");
        }
        if(selected === "rect"){ 
            alert("drag and drop for rect");
        }
    };
</script>
```